# RegEx for extracting image file links

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What would be the best way to use RegEx to extract links of picture files from a large string?

```
http://<linkhere>.jpg
http://<linkhere>.png
http://<linkhere>.gif
```

etc.? But in one expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
http://(\\S+?)\\.(jpg|png|gif)
```

e.g.:

```
string s = "http://link1.jpg bha http://link2.png blahblah http://link3.gif";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "http://(\\S+?)\\.(jpg|png|gif)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Yeah - I posted my original comment before I saw your code example, so I deleted my comment.  Someday I'll learn patience.  Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: Does C#'s regex engine understand `\s` and `\S`? Might be better than `[^ ]`.